How do I merge these two Docker JSON files into one
I want to move my Docker installation to another drive mounted here /mnt/disk1/docker So I followed some instructions and also added this bit of text to the the /docker/daemon.json file
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/disk1/docker"
}

Now Ineed to install the Nvidia CUDA container toolkit to enable CUDA, however it created a new /docker/daemon.json file with this content:
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}

I just cant figure out how to add both of these of the same file so my docker install also works with nvidia.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I'll post the answer I got elsewhere:
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/disk1/docker",
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}

